# Strange CSS behaviour, cannot see what is taking the space up

Tags: css

My website header is where I have my menu.  Except I am having to put a negative margin on it and I don't want to do that, but for some reason, there is something taking up space between the hgroup and the nav element.  I thought it might be the form element for the search box, but when I do display:block it makes no difference.  The site is [here](http://nicolaelvin.com/community/crime-safety/).

Another strange thing is when I hover over a submenu (e.g. recycle) the parent element goes white.  I can't for the life of me work out why.  See below for strange hover behaviour.

[image: white hover problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design changed right after I refreshed your website. As for now, all I see is that the navigation is still `1px` off the header. Maybe if you'd reduce the `margin-top` from `42px` to `41px`, that problem will be solved.

EDIT:
So in Chrome, there's this `1px` issue, but in Firefox, it looks fine.
The same `1px` offset in Safari and Opera. But again, in IE8, it looks fine.
I think this problem has occurred due to the defined height for hgroup, if you have done that.

[image: The screenshot from Chrome]
[image: The screenshot from Firefox]

[ *the first image is a screenshot from Chrome, the second is from Firefox* ]

EDIT 2:
The offset is due to the fixed height of the background image. Other than that, everything is working just fine. Obviously, there are variations in both the images, as you can see, the chrome having the `1px` offset while it is absent in Firefox. I, personally don't like to give a defined height to elements that is likely to have results like above.
One good solution would be to make a header container with 100% width and the given background image, while all the header content will go within the container. That way, no matter how high the contents within the container are, the background will remain the way it is meant to, and your navigation will not get an offset.

Comment: thanks for that.  I don't have a height on my hgroup, I just have padding on my h1 to allow for the size of the bg img logo.  Also, have you any ideas as to the weird hover issue?

Comment: I really can't give you much advice for the hover issue because the CSS seems fine to me. I guess the screenshot you provided was from Opera because here in my PC, Opera is the only browser that gave the same output. FF, Chrome, Safari and even IE8 (ie, except for ``border-radius`` and ``box-shadow`` for IE) have given the desired output regarding the hover effect.
But if you could reduce the value of ``top`` from the sub-menu, you **may, but not necessarily** get a proper result. Now I'm not very sure about that, and I don't believe it will work. But you can try it once.

Comment: #access ul ul{
 top:2.65em; <---- this value ...
 width:auto;
 margin:0px;
}

Answer (score 1):

Make your body background longer?

Answer (score 0):

```
<h2 id="site-description"></h2>
```

If you use Firebug/Inspect element, you'll see it there, just after your h1, taking up a lot of space.

```
#site-description {
color: #7A7A7A;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 0 270px 3.65625em 0;
}
```

For the White hover in the nav, make the following change:

```
#access ul ul {
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: thank you, I don't know why I didn't see that!  I don't suppose you know answer to the white hover problem do you?  I can't inspect with firebug because it i only on hover of the child menu item

Comment: No it's not that, it's the li parent that goes white on hover of the child items

Comment: I see it, there's a gap, if you go slow it disappears, if you go fast it stays up. It's not going white, your UL is in the wrong position on hover (chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Yea h2 description is taking space from your header and about your menu, try splitting your rules in mainnav.css, seems like you have :hover grouped with actives, that's why your classes are messing up

This is the rule causing the problem in your css

```
 #access #menu-menu li.current_page_item a, #access #menu-menu li.current_page_item, #access #menu-menu li.current_page_item a:hover, #access #menu-menu li.current_page_item:hover {
    background-color: #FAFAF0;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #0F0D0C;
```

Comment: it's not that, I've changed it so it's only on the a and a:hover